# Add json object to existing json array

Tags: android, json, gson

Hi I want to update an existing json array by adding new object to it. How can this be done in Android.

My json is lying on a remote machine and I am using GSON to parse the JSON.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

```
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
        String finalJson="";
        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

        try {

           HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(getRequest);

           final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

           if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) { 
              Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error " + statusCode + " for URL " + url); 
              return null;
           }

           HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
           finalJson=EntityUtils.toString(getResponseEntity);
           System.out.println("getResponse.."+s);


        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
           getRequest.abort();
           Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error for URL " + url, e);
        }

        finalJson=finalJson.substring(source.indexOf("[")+1)+"\"object:\"" ; // your logic to append object
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        parseJsonClass response = gson.fromJson(source, parseJsonClass .class);
```

from the i hope you can get the idea what i mean to say